# iPhone GSM chatter causes USB interference / disconnects

Tags: iphone, usb, gsm

When my (first gen) iPhone does some GSM transmitting (which I can hear through my speakers as very loud chatter), my usb mouse will occasionally disconnect and reconnect.

My iPhone isn't physically connected to my pc... just laying on the desk near it.

Has anyone seen anything like this?  Should I be worried about my iPhone or just a defect of the mouse?  (MS Optical Mouse 3000)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is sort of normal and expected. You could definitely try getting a new mouse, with a higher quality cable (read: more shielding).

I would also suggest placing your phone on something relatively large and metal, or just find a new position on your desk where the interference is minimal.